# Error using R1C1 notations in Formula on Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, excel-r1c1-notation

I've encountered some issues on my new Macro.

In fact, I'm translating a VBA Macro in Google Apps Script language but I don't understand something.

Instructions :

```
  feuille_31.insertColumnAfter(8); // Inserting a new column
  feuille_31.getRange(1,9).setValue(libel); // Rename my column.
  feuille_31.getRange("I2"+":I"+lig).setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[0]C[-2]:R[0]C[-1])");
  // SUM between the value in column -2 and column -1.
```

I literraly copied google syntax for this :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
// This sets the formula to be the sum of the 3 rows above B5
cell.setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])");
```

But I'm still getting this type of error :
[Screen of my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZyJP.png)

I've read some things about INDIRECT but I don't really understand how to use that and if that could be useful on what I'm dealing with.

If someone could explain to me why I'm getting an #ERROR, what is wrong with my instruction, it could be very nice.

Thanks for reading.
Thinkpad23

Answer (score 1):

You can not copy/paste the `=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])` parameter as a formula, it only works when executed with Google Apps Script by calling the `setFormulaR1C1` function, which parses the rows and columns values and returns a valid formula.

In your case, for cell "I3" Apps Script would end up converting `cell.setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[0]C[-2]:R[0]C[-1])");` to `=SUM(G3:H3)`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you mean, but actually, I don't understand the purpose then, of the setFormulaR1C1 function if we can't use R1C1 notations? 

I'm just following the example given by Google...
Sorry if I get your answer wrong, I don't understand everything because of the language barrier.


Thinkpad23

Comment: Do you know how to run a function using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to use R1C1 notation, you must use INDIRECT with the second parameter FALSE, i.e.

```
=INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]",FALSE)+INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]",FALSE)
```

nevertheless, with google sheets you should better use arrayformula at the top of the column

```
={"QTE_APRES";ARRAYFORMULA(G2:G+H2:H)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helps me a lot.

Have a nice day.

Thinkpad23.